# GitLab Visibility Settings CLI

Tags: git, gitlab, command-line-interface

In GitLab, is it possible to change a repository's visibility using commands after creating a project as explained [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try this cli tool: https://github.com/profclems/glab

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Gitlab [Project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#edit-project) :

Example to change the visibility of your project (with id 281) to private :

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOURTOKEN" -X PUT https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/281?visibility=private
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I don't have a private token. I can just ssh.

Comment: An ssh URL can be used to clone/pull/push but not to manage the repository. To use Gitlab API you need https URL, login and password.

Comment: you can generate your own token wth api scope following these [instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token)